# Where to add calls to use the Flurry SDK in my Unity2D project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, flurry-analytics

I am developing a 2D Android game with unity3D, and I wanna integrate Flurry SDK to my project, I imported the Flurry SDK & plugin but I don't know exactly where to add the call to use Flurry in my project?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you are using the plugin provided by Flurry; the answer below may not apply if using a third party plugin.)

You should initialize Flurry as early as possible in the main program loop.